# Is the weak star limit of Radon measure a Radon measure?

Tags: measure-theory

I guess the title already gave a quite precise idea of what the question will be. Say $(\mu_k)$ is a sequence of Radon measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ converging weakly* to a measure $\mu$. Is $\mu$ then Radon itself?